# Bootcamp Windows 7 installed but no wifi capability or USB drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootcamp, windows

So I installed Bootcamp with Windows 7 Professional on my late 2013 15in Macbook Pro with Retina and I have it installed and booting up Windows 7, however it doesn't seem to pick up any of my hardware (Aside from my keyboard and trackpad). I read that the solution it to download the bootcamp udpate, but I have no way of getting it on the Windows partioned hard drive it it doesn't pick up my USB. It also does not let me drag and drop the update file into the Windows hard drive while using OS X.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: How did you install the software if the USB does not work? I assume you can start a command window after booting using the installation flash drive. So, I wonder if you can copy files to this flash drive using OS X before booting.

Comment: The USB booted up fine during the installation process. It was only when Windows was successfully installed that it no longer picked up any of my drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific instance, there was no way for me to solve this issue without going through the process all over again from the beginning.

I went back into OS X and removed the Windows partition from my system. I reinstalled the Bootcamp partition and the ISO file onto the USB following these instructions: https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1583/en_US/boot_camp_install-setup_10.7.pdf

This time when Windows booted up for the first time, Bootcamp booted up along with it and installed al the drivers.

Thanks all for you answers!

Answer (score 2):

[Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) is an app that makes NTFS filesystems fully readable & writable. There is a 15-Day trial for it. So you can download Windows Support, and just put it into for example your `C:\Users\User\Desktop` instead of putting it on a USB.

If you cannot find the BOOTCAMP partition on your Desktop. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and type `/Volumes/` and there search for your Windows partition. And then you just drag & drop the Windows Support file to your Windows Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Wi-Fi on bootcamp Windows 7, you must install external driver for Wi-Fi.

BroadcomWirelessWin7x32 driver compatible with 32 or 64 OS.

Get more about that i fixed on my Macbook bootcamp installed windows 7.

[Wi-Fi not working on windows 7 MacBook boot camp](http://www.best4advise.com/wi-fi-not-working-on-windows-7-macbook-boot-camp/)